# Converting HTML to DOCX

Tags: html, maven, docx, doc, file-conversion

I'm looking for all existent possibilities to convert an `HTML` document to a `DOCX` one.

**Context :**

I have some documentation that it's written and maintained in HTML (No complex thing, just simples `H1`, `H2`, `P`, `IMG` elements), and I would like to convert them into `word` documents.

A `Maven` plugin would be great, or something that could allow me to do this conversion during the release phase of my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclosure: docx4j is "my" project**

docx4j can do this, for well-formed XHTML.  See the [ConvertInXHTML* examples](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/tree/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples).

docx4j-ImportXHTML is in Maven Central: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j-ImportXHTML/8.0.0/jar

If you want a Maven plugin, you'll have to create that yourself.

Comment: the links are all broken